# Js Chrome dev tools prints Array with length but no children

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

You can see in the screenshot that all three Arrays has lengths, but no children. Why that happens? Is it because Garbage collection hasn't collected and space for items is still reserved?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible the array was initialized with so many elements? For example `new Array(10)` declares a new array with length 10, but it would be empty.

Comment: Is it the fact it chrome lazy loads array/object data until you open it?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: Version 76.0. Array comes in `ngOnInit` hook (Angular), from the injected service property

Answer (score 0):

What version of chrome are you on? It is likely you have an empty array of size 10.

```
var test = {
    myArray: new Array(10)
};

console.log(test)
```

This results in an array of length 10 but the items are not initialized. In some versions of chrome, for example you could not use the map function on an uninitialized array.

Comment: Well, not in my case, unless Angular does something like this under the hood

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrom 76 also. In my console it give me the info empties

[image]